# How to Include external word document between the lyx document

Tags: lyx, external-files, include

I am writing my thesis, have to include a word file consists of 5 to 6 pages between the LyX document. 
Kindly help me by telling how can I include an external file in LyX document.

Comment: In general you can't include word files in latex. The simplest solution may be just to produce the latex/lyx part separately and then merge the pages using external pdftools at the end.

Comment: Actually that is the file having a programming language which should be included in the middle. Okay, can I change page numbers manually?

Comment: Oh if it is code listing why do you want to include it as a word file? just put the code itself into the latex document using verbatim or listings environment. (If you do want to splice in a word file later you can use `\clearpage\addtocounter{page}{6}` to leave a gap in the page numbers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to use the Word document, you could first create a PDF from Word and then include the PDF pages in your LyX document. By doing it through LyX, you avoid having to post-process as suggested by David Carlisle.

Personally, I recreate in LyX, the content from Word, et al, if at all possible.

Comment: How I would add that (pdf converted file from word) into LyX, what would be the procedure? Does this effect on page numbers??

Comment: Insert->File->External Material (use PDF pages). The pages are inserted into your document and included in the page count, though the PDF pages themselves are not numbered. Read the documentation and experiment.